# How to change Ext Js Button tooltip at runtime?

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, tooltip

I have the following:

```
var panel = headerPanel.add({
    id: 'recentcommands_button_id',
    xtype: 'button',
    text: "Recent Commands",
    tooltip: "Sample Tooltip Text"
});
```

Followed later on by:

```
Ext.getCmp('recentcommands_button_id').tooltip = "TEST";
```

Which sets the tooltip value properly if I check the button's properties, but which does not actually change the value on the screen.

I tried using:

```
Ext.getCmp('recentcommands_button_id').tooltip.update("TEST");
```

This did not work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setTooltip](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-method-setTooltip) method:

```
Ext.getCmp('recentcommands_button_id').setTooltip("TEST");
```

Comment: Could you improve your answer by saying what was wrong, what you fixed, etc?